# Teradata: [Error 1154] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while inserting the batch of rows

Tags: sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, batch-processing, teradata

I have connected to my Teradata database via JDBC and  am trying to use the FASTLOAD utility of Teradata to insert records into a table (with prepared statements and batch). Eg:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:teradata://192.168.1.110/TYPE=FASTLOAD", "admin", "admin");

String sql = "INSERT INTO table (RANDOM_INTEGER) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

int numberOfRecordsToInsert = 100000;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRecordsToInsert; i++) {

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 5);
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

        }

preparedStatement.executeBatch();

connection.commit();
```

With this (I've tried this on many different tables with different data types) I get the following error when it gets to the executeBatch() line:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata
>   JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.14] [Error 1154] [SQLState HY000] A
>   failure occurred while inserting the batch of rows destined for
>   database table "admin"."table". Details of the failure can be
>   found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
>     at
>   com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:148)
>     at
>   com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:132)
>     at
>   com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2202)
>     at teradata.fastload.main(fastload.java:62) Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.14]
>   [Error 1147] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the exception
>   chain occurred while beginning FastLoad of database table
>   "admin"."table"   at
>   com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:94)
>     at
>   com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:69)
>     at
>   com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.beginFastLoad(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:836)
>     at
>   com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2070)
>     ... 1 more

I don't know how to even call the getNextException that the error says.

Comment: try printStackTrace() in the catch clause, that could relate you better to the cause of error.

Comment: yes printstacktrace just says what I've quoted above

Comment: the problem seems to be TYPE=FASTLOAD, as removing it works for us. The target tables are empty/fresh/newly created, as that appears to be a requirement for FASTLOAD so not sure if it is causing the issue. Did you manage the solve it ?