# Failed to insert the data into Teradata using FastLoadUtil using java

Tags: java, teradata

I'm trying to insert the data into teradata using preparedstatement of  java application using Teradata FastloadUtil. But I'm facing  the below exception :

```
Rolling back because of error: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.00.00.37] [Error 1154] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while inserting the batch of rows destined for database table "mydb.tablename". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
```

But, I'm able to insert the data into destined table of teradata using normal TeradataUtility but not fastload.

I have seen the similar exception [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449948/teradata-error-1154-sqlstate-hy000-a-failure-occurred-while-inserting-the-b) but with no clues in that site too.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose without know WHY it failed. This error just stats THAT it failed. Are you able to get the results from `getNextException` (I don't know how to do that either, so I'll be of no help for that part).

Comment: catch (SQLException exc) { exc.getNextException().printStackTrace(); }

Comment: Do we have any specifications of creating a table for fastload utility in Teradata ?

Comment: There are no specifications for creating a table that will be fastloaded. A fastloaded table just needs to be empty before fastloading `DELETE FROM <table>;` Other than that it should be ready for load via Fastload, TPT, Mload, or individual `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur info @JNevill. Finally, I'm able to resolve my issue and I'm able to load the data into Teradata. Actually, the issue was with the preparedstatement. It was not allowing all the parameters as dynamic parameters while inserting . We need to manipulate atleast one parameter in the preparedstatement while inserting.